# Trying to access the Rest API for the Camunda 8 Self hosted python

Tags: python, rest, camunda

Hi i've been trying to access the camunda restfull api to get the tasklist but i'm stuck at the very first step where i need to autheticate the user

I found [this reference url](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-clients/console-api-reference/) but it seems to be for camunda cloud

I'm looking for the self hosted client and access the api from the third party like jet admin

Let me know if there is any confusion or need clearification

Comment: Do you have any code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If I read the linked documentation, I see [this part](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/tasklist-deployment/tasklist-authentication/#identity).

[image]

Then clicking on [the link there](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/tasklist-deployment/tasklist-authentication/#identity) it explains how to set up the authentication for the self-managed version.

[image]

Comment: Configure identity is the place where i get stuck and though i have followed the guide ....there is a step where application is suppose to be attached some permissions which is also nt available at local self hosted currently

Answer (score 0):

for self hosted Camunda you need this [docs](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/reference/rest/task/get-query/) about the rest API.

As you say, the problem now is authentication - so you get 401/403 error code?
By default Camunda uses Basic authentication (you can then add LDAP plugin, e.g. for Keycloak) and the default admin credentials are `demo/demo` (look [here](https://forum.camunda.io/t/no-initial-admin-user-creation-page/696/2?u=raliev)).

So if you get 403, then you can set Basic Auth with this user/password, try it to send in Postman:

[image: GET task list by Camunda REST API]